# want to set two xpath in to one and get there attribute value in diff. array

Tags: php, xml, xpath

this is my reg.xml file:-

```
<childrens>
<child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
    <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
    <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
        <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
    </child_10067>
    </child_10066>
</child_4>
<child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="2">
    <child_5069 entity_id="5069" value="Rajkot" parent_id="4331"/>
</child_4331>
</childrens>
```

this is my product.xml:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="5"/>
      <dist_activity value="10068"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="5"/>
      <dist_activity value="10069"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="4457"/>
      <dist_region value="7140"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
   </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

tried:-

```
<?php
 $abc= "One Day in Rajkot";
 list($first,$second) = explode(' in ',$abc);

 $text1[]=$first;
 $text2[]=$second;
 foreach($text1 as $event)
{
$event;
}
foreach($text2 as $region1)
{
$region1;
}
$r = file_get_contents('reg.xml');
$p = file_get_contents('product.xml');

$region = simplexml_load_string($r);
$product = simplexml_load_string($p);

list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$event']/@entity_id");
$entity=(string)$entity;

list($entity1) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$region1']/@entity_id");
$entity1=(string)$entity1;

//check the $entity in product.xml
list($prid) = $product->xpath("//*[@value='$entity']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
$prid=(string)$prid;
echo "Event:- $event, Region:- $region1, entity1:- $entity, entity2:- $entity1, Product_id:- $prid";
 ?>
```

i am try to pass one string in array and split in to diff. array and this value are check in `reg.xml` if reg.xml have this value then get there `entity_id` this id is match on `product.xml` then return `product_id` from `product.xml`

my code work fine but i want to set both xpath in one

```
    list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$event']/@entity_id");
    $entity=(string)$entity;

    list($entity1) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$region1']/@entity_id");
    $entity1=(string)$entity1;
```

i want to set both this path in to one i try something like this:-

```
list($entity,$entity1) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$event']and[@value='$region1']/@entity_id");
    $entity=(string)$entity;
```

please help me out with this...

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine two predicates with an `and` like you did:

```
[@value='$event']and[@value='$region1']
```

However you can use an `or` *inside* the predicate:

```
[@value='$event' or @value='$region1']
```

This should then do the job. For your further information, you can have multiple predicates *after* each other, however, there are no operators like `and` between them:

```
 [@value='$event' or @value='$region1'][1]
```

Example: Only take the first one.